# Поменять владельца файла или директории

Tags: c++, c, linux, права, chown

Как в c++ поменять права на файл или директорию? Знаю, есть функция `chown`, но она в виде аргументов принимает не строки, а id пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться этими функциями для получения нужных вам идентификаторов:

- [getpwnam](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) — function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-out fields of the record in the password database (e.g., the local password file */etc/passwd*, NIS, and LDAP) that matches the username *name*.
- [getgrnam](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getgrnam) — function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-out fields of the record in the group database (e.g., the local group file */etc/group*, NIS, and LDAP) that matches the group name *name*.